# Creating Function to count user's commits in a database

Tags: sql-server, database, function

I have a database with users and a data base with commits that include the user that made the commit. I made a select returning the count of each user's commit but I need help making that into function.
The select that I made is :

```
SELECT u.Username, COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM Users AS u
JOIN Commits AS c ON C.ContributorId = u.Id
GROUP BY u.Username
```

And I receive

```
------------------------------ -----------
ANinedsa                       2
AryaDenotehow                  3
AryaNinehow                    3
BlaAntigadsa                   3
BlaSinduxrein                  2
DarkImmagidsa                  1
HighAsmahow                    3
RoundAntigaBel                 5
RoundArmydsa                   2
RoundInspecindi                2
ScoreAntigarein                4
ScoreImmagidefon               4
ScoreSinduxIana                1
TheDivineBel                   2
UnderSinduxrein                6
UnveiledDenoteIana             1
WhatTerrorBel                  3
ZendArmyhow                    3
```

My question is how can I make function that returns the count.
Example :

```
SELECT dbo.udf_AllUserCommits('UnderSinduxrein')
```

Output

```
6
```

Comment: You should read the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) before asking a question on here. And if there is any chance at all you might embed this function in another query, use an inline table valued function for better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_AllUserCommits
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here    
    @username NVARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
   -- Declare the return variable here
   DECLARE @cnt INT

   -- Get number of commits for specified user
   SET @cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM Users AS u
               JOIN Commits AS c ON C.ContributorId = u.Id
               WHERE Username = @username)

   -- Return the result of the function
   RETURN (@cnt);
END
```

Comment: No real benefit from declaring a local variable when you can directly return the result of the query.

Comment: @DaleK Yes, I agree, I just wanted to make the code easier to understand.